# How to get the latest DefinitelyTyped for a specific version of a tool in github

Tags: jquery, git, github, definitelytyped

Sorry, maybe this is a simple question, but how can you get the latest version of DefinitelyTyped for a specific version of a tool on GitHub?

In NuGet, DefinitelyTyped points to jQuery version 2.4.X, but I want use version 3.1.1 instead.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/

I went straight to GitHub to get the latest version—version 3.1.1, but I wasn't able to find it.
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/jquery

Comment: I'm not a NuGet user, but it looks to me like NuGet already has version 3.1.1 (and also 3.1.2, which is marked as current).

Comment: I think 3.1.2 is the version of the NuGet DefinitelyTyped for JQuery, not the version that it should refer to, do you know what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

According to the page in the Nuget Gallery, that the package was generated from commit: 2c65d5ca7267fda6d49a3b447c8b089632fb5358

You can view the filesystem of the plugin at that commit [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/2c65d5ca7267fda6d49a3b447c8b089632fb5358/jquery/).

Just clone the repository and checkout that commit.

`git checkout 2c65d5ca726`

This will detach the head and give a nasty looking warning, but it's ok. To get out of the detached head state, just run `git checkout master`